# Using boost::range::sort

Tags: c++, sorting, boost

I's appreciate an example of how to use `boost::sort` (I'm trying to sort a custom-made container of objects, and therefore cannot use `std::sort`). The example in the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/mutating/sort.html) is very scant; besides I can't find any information about how to create a `RandomAccessRange`.

Comment: That sounds like an XY problem. You don't know how to use `std::sort`, so while flailing around you stumbled upon `boost::sort` - but you don't know how to use that either. I suggest you start from the beginning and describe what's so special about your custom-made container that you (think you) can't use `std::sort` with it.

Comment: `boost::sort` uses `std::sort`. So if you can't use `std::sort` on your container, then you can't use `boost::sort`.

Comment: I *do* know how to use `std::sort`. But as I said I have implemented my own container and iterator (long story) and they do not have some `std::iterator_traits` required by `boost::range::sort`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I have taken a look at the source for `boost::range:sort` and if I understand correctly, boost sorts the range (`RandomAccessRange`) and not the container elements. Is this correct? If it is, then only the range needs to be compatible with `boost::range::sort`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *"sorts the range ... and not the container elements"* -- When you pass it a container, the range *is* the container elements. You can pass it something smaller than your container, such as a subset of your container (via `boost::iterator_range`, for example). In that case, the range is a subset of your container elements. And all `boost::sort` does with that subset (besides concept checking), is this: `std::sort(boost::begin(rng), boost::end(rng));`

Comment: `they do not have some std::iterator_traits` What's stopping you from providing the same? Or providing necessary typedefs in your custom iterator class so that the standard implementation works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't create a RandomAccessRange.

You *have* ranges. And it should be possible to get the random-access iterators from that using the default methods (`std::begin(r)`, `boost::begin(r)`, or `r.begin()`, also `cbegin`)

```
auto r1 = "I am a range of char";
auto r2 = "me too!";
auto r3[] = { r1, r2 }; // a range of const char*
auto r4 = std::vector<std::string> { r1, r2 }; // two strings
auto r5 = std::list<std::string> { begin(r3), end(r3) }; // idem
```

Now regardless of how you got the range, you can either use

```
std::sort(begin(r), end(r));
```

or use Boost's range version:

```
boost::sort(r);
```

As you can see, boost::sort is merely syntactic sugar for doing exactly the same

A full sample: **Note** the subtleties of what sorting predicate is used (see `std::less<>` there)

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1aacfe199d03dfb4)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

using namespace boost;

int main() {
    auto r1 = "I am a range of char";
    auto r2 = "me too!";
    const char* r3[] = { r1, r2 }; // a range of const char*
    auto r4 = std::vector<std::string> { r1, r2 }; // two strings
    auto r5 = std::list<std::string> { begin(r3), end(r3) }; // idem

    std::sort(begin(r3), end(r3)); // sorts by pointer value
    boost::sort(r3);               // sorts by pointer value

    std::sort(begin(r3), end(r3), std::less<std::string>()); // sorts the strings
    boost::sort(r3, std::less<std::string>());               // sorts the strings
    //// but this won't compile:
    // boost::sort(r5); // not random traversal category
}
```

Comment: @lubgr thanks for the edit. I misread it at first. I guess I was confused by the dead code in the sample. Anyways, fixed it! (There doesn't seem to be a way to undo my edit rejection :()